# How to send cross domain ajax request with JSON response

Tags: jquery

I want to send a cross domain ajax request, but the server only provides JSON(**Not JSONP**) response, is there anyway to make the request ?

Here's what i've did:

```
var url='http://*******:***/rest/code/results.json'+'?AddressLine1='+ad1+'&City='+city+'&StateProvince='+sp+'&PostalCode='+pc+'&Country='+cn; 


$.ajax({
    url:url,
    dataType:"jsonp",
    type:'get',
    processData:false,
    crossDomain:true,
    contentType:"application/json",
    success: function (Output) {
       alert(JSON.stringify(Output));
           alert(Output);
       }
```

});
The response is :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Syntax error: try like this: `sucess:function (result)`

Comment: The output as you know is a JSON string. Changing the `dataType` option to `json` will solve the *Unexpected token* error. *And you will then get the expected `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error*

Comment: Doing a *curl* for this from the server side may be the best option.

Comment: Not sure if you can do JSON cross-domain request. Maybe you should consider using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing); however I never used it so I can't help you further with it.

Comment: @techfoobar correct but could/should be against site TOS

Comment: @roasted - Yes, that ofcourse needs to be considered. I believe the OP will use his research and best judgement to decide that. :-)

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić thats why OP uses JSONP -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @ techfoobar:
Thank you, Exactly what u said is right. But how to resolve that Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Comment: But I dont have an option to change server side code. It gives output either in xml or json format only

Comment: I think server need to wrap the json in en envelop

Comment: @Arun Killu: Can u please brief explain on ur comment , i dont understand?

Comment: @Arun - I meant adding a curl based fetcher on your server, not dict.qq.com - But do look into the TOS of the site you are fetching from.

Comment: @DKM: Its not the issue, i updated the question. Still I am facing the same problem

Comment: @Arun i assume you have no control over the web server providing the web service ?does they provide jsonp ?

Comment: @Arun Killu: That provides json/xml output

Comment: then only way is to use a server side script to read data .